How displaying modal window on react
The modal window is displayed behind other elements on the page(red element on screen)
enter image description here
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    }
    
    render() {
        const { active, setActive } = this.props; // Получаем active и setActive из props

        return (
            <div className={modal ${active ? 'active' : ''}}>
                <div className="modal-content">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Modal;

.modal{
    z-index: 4;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
using z-index did not help
